# ExpressionTree and IEnumerable implementation

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have the following Generic class that receives a type T and must implement IEnumerable:

```
public class ConfigurationHelper<T>: IEnumerable<object[]> where T: BaseTestConfiguration 
{
    public T _configuration;

    public ConfigurationHelper(configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ParameterExpression element = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "element");
        //use reflection to check the property that's a generic list
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in _configuration.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties())
        {
        }

       /* HERE IS MY ISSUE */
       return _configuration.Select(x=>GET LIST<OTHERTYPE> PROPERTY)
                            .SelectMany(i => new object[] { AS MANY PROPERTIES AS OTHERTYPE  })
                            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The only thing that I know from my type T its that have only one property type `List<OtherType>`, and I would like to return an `IEnumerable<object[]>` with as many items as properties in this OtherType.

I would like to use ExpressionTrees for that, but  I don't know how to compose it.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Use pseudo-code to express it.

Comment: In current code you will run the whole LINQ query every time you start enumeration.

Comment: Hi, Can you please give me some definition of BaseTestConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really do something much without definition of BestTestConfiguration. If you can provide it, I will change the code. Please check the below code what I tried to do from my understanding:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var helper = new ConfigurationHelper<BestTestConfiguration>(new BestTestConfiguration()
            {
                Objects = new List<string>()
                {
                    "testing 1",
                    "testing 2"
                }
            });
            var item = helper.GetEnumerator();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

    public class ConfigurationHelper<T> : IEnumerable<object[]> where T : BestTestConfiguration
    {
        public T Configuration;

        public ConfigurationHelper(T configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            ParameterExpression element = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "element");
            //use reflection to check the property that's a generic list
            var items = new List<object[]>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in Configuration.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType))
            {
                var valueOfProperty = Configuration.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(Configuration, null);
                items.Add(new object[] {valueOfProperty});
            }

            return items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class BestTestConfiguration
    {
        public List<string> Objects { get; set; }
    }
```